# crear base de datos en microsoft azure desde codigo c#

Tags: c#, azure, base-de-datos

estoy intentando crear una base de datos con un programa escrito en c#. Me he creado una cuenta gratuita y he creado un recurso de azure cosmos db. La conexión con la cuenta de cosmos db se realiza correctamente pero a la hora de crear la base de datos no obtengo respuesta se queda ahy esperando. Es posible que necesite una subscripción mayor para poder hacer esto?
El código es el siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace AzureApp
{
  class Program
  {
    private const string EndpointUrl = "<endpoint>";
    private const string PrimaryKey = "<privatekey>";
    private DocumentClient client;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.GetStartedDemo().Wait();
        }
        catch (DocumentClientException de)
        {
            Exception baseException = de.GetBaseException();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} error occurred: {1}, Message: {2}", de.StatusCode, de.Message, baseException.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Exception baseException = e.GetBaseException();
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}, Message: {1}", e.Message, baseException.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("End of demo, press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    private async Task GetStartedDemo()
    {
        this.client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUrl), PrimaryKey);

        await this.client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(new Database { Id = "FamilyDB" });
    }

    private void WriteToConsoleAndPromptToContinue(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(format, args);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue ...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo estas siguiente los pasos de esta documentacion

[Azure Cosmos DB: SQL API getting started tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-get-started)

ya que el codigo que observo es identico al que has puesto

Creo que el primer paso seria valida ademas que el `EndpointUrl` y la `PrimaryKey` son correctas, esto es fundamental

Ahora tambien recomendaria intentes aplicar estos otros pasos

[Quickstart: Build a .NET web app with Azure Cosmos DB using the SQL API and the Azure portal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-sql-api-dotnet)

como veras difiere con el anterior ya que crea la db directamente en el portal, quizas algun tema con la funcionalidad de la creacion de la db este afectando el codigo, por eso podrias crear la db desde el portal y solo conectarte

En este otro ejemplo se usa

```
await client.CreateDatabaseAsync(new Database { Id = DatabaseId });
```

es diferente al  `CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync()`, pero recomendaria veas de ya tener la db creada a ver si resulta

Por otro lado si quieres validar la conectividad, podrias ver de usar el

[Manage Azure Cosmos DB in Azure Storage Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/storage-explorer)

como observaras es una applicacion que se descarga y podras conectarte a la suscripcion de cosmos db

Otra alternativa seria

[CosmosDbExplorer](https://github.com/sachabruttin/CosmosDbExplorer)

es una aplicacion desktop que si bien esta el codigo, veras alli que puedes descarcar el .exe

Otra forma es con un plugin de VS Code

[Azure Cosmos DB](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-cosmosdb#overview)

como veras hay varias formas de podes administrar cosmos db y validar si puedes crear la db teniendo acceso, seria raro que pudiendo administrarla con estas tools no puedas hacerlo desde codigo

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias probare las herramientas para conectarme a las cosmosdb. Lo de crear la db y la collección en el cloud directamente lo he hecho y se me queda pillado a la hora de escribir datos alli, no ejecuta ninguna instruccion ni da error ni nada. Creo que debe ser algo de la subscripción que tengo. Probaré usando las herramientas que me has proporcionado gracias

Comment: no entendi lo de pillado? te refieres a al portal de azure, o  creas la db en el portal y se queda tu aplicacion cuando quiere realizar una query